# Random generation with TRNG

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, trng

For the following code which generates random numbers for Monte Carlo simulation, I need to receive the exact sum for each run, but this will not happen, although I have fixed the seed. I would appreciate it if anyone could point out the problem with this code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cfloat>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <omp.h>
#include <trng/yarn2.hpp>
#include <trng/mt19937_64.hpp>
#include <trng/uniform01_dist.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;
const double landa = 1; 
const double exact_solution = landa / (pow(landa, 2) + 1); 
double function(double x) {
    return cos(x) / landa;
}

int main() {
    int rank; 
    const int N = 1000000;
    double sum = 0.0;
    trng::yarn2 r[6];
    for (int i = 0; i <6; i++)
    { 
        r[i].seed(0); 
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
          r[i].split(6,i);
    }
    
     trng::uniform01_dist<double> u;
     auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
     #pragma omp parallel  num_threads(6)  
     {
         rank=omp_get_thread_num();
         #pragma omp for reduction (+: sum)
         for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i) {
            //double x = distribution(g);
      
            double x= u(r[rank]); 
            x = (-1.0 / landa) * log(1.0 - x); 
            sum = sum+function(x);
         }
    }
     double app   = sum / static_cast<double> (N);
     auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
        
    auto diff=duration_cast<milliseconds>(end-start);
    
    cout << "Approximation is: " <<setprecision(17) << app << "\t"<<"Time: "<< setprecision(17) << diff.count()<<" Error: "<<(app-exact_solution)<< endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** The problem is two-fold:

1. Floating point addition is not associative;
2. You are generating different random number for each thread.

---

> I need to receive the exact sum for each run, but this will not
> happen, although I have fixed the seed. I would appreciate it if
> anyone could point out the problem with this code

First, you have a *race-condition* on `rank=omp_get_thread_num();`, the variable `rank` is shared among all threads, to fix that you can declared the variable `rank` inside the parallel region, hence, making it private to each thread.

```
 #pragma omp parallel  num_threads(6)  
 {
     int rank=omp_get_thread_num();
     ...
  }
```

In your code, you should not expect that the value of the `sum` will be the same for different number of threads. Why ?

1. because you are adding `doubles` in parallel

   ```
       double sum = 0.0;
       ...
       #pragma omp for reduction (+: sum)
       for (int i = 0; i<N; ++i) {
           //double x = distribution(g);

           double x= u(r[rank]); 
           x = (-1.0 / landa) * log(1.0 - x); 
           sum = sum+function(x);
       }
   ```

   and from [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know about Floating
   Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) one can read:

   > Another grey area concerns the interpretation of parentheses. **Due to roundoff errors, the associative laws of algebra do not necessarily hold for floating-point numbers.** For example, the
   > expression (x+y)+z has a totally different answer than x+(y+z) when
   > x = 1e30, y = -1e30 and z = 1 (it is 1 in the former case, 0 in the
   > latter).

   Hence, from that you conclude that floating point addition is not
   associative, and the reason why for a different number of threads you might have different `sum` values.
2. You are generating different random values *per* thread:

   ```
     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
     {
         r[i].split(6,i);
     }
   ```

   Consequently, for different number of threads, the variable `sum`
   gets different results as well.

As kindly point out by [jérôme-richard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12939557/j%C3%A9r%C3%B4me-richard) in the comments:

> Note that more precise algorithm like the [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) can
> significantly reduces the rounding issue while being still relatively
> fast.

Comment: @MAero2020 you are under the wrong impression about floats and doubles, doubles are  double-floating points. they have the same issues that float has but less pronounce because they can represent numbers with a higher precision. A computer cannot represent infinite precision like math can and that is where the problems comes from